# Problemas com Sockets

Tags: javascript, java

Estou criando uma aplicação que precisa **mandar e receber informações** de uma página da web através de **Sockets**, o servidor em Java eu consegui fazer, mas não entendo muito de JS, poderiam me ajudar a fazer o cliente que envia e recebe mensagens em **JavaScript para web** e que se conecte a este servidor em Java que fiz?

Código do servidor:
**Servidor.java**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    System.out.println("Inicia servidor.");

    ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(3000);

    System.out.println("Aguardando conexão.");

    Socket socket = server.accept();

    System.out.println("Conexão estabelecida.");

    InputStream input = socket.getInputStream();
    OutputStream output = socket.getOutputStream();

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
    PrintStream out = new PrintStream(output);

    while (true) {
        String mensagem = in.readLine();

        System.out.println(
                "Mensagem recebida do cliente [" +
                        socket.getInetAddress().getHostName() +
                        "]: " +
                        mensagem);
        if ("FIM".equals(mensagem)){
            break;
        }

        out.println(mensagem);
    }

    System.out.println("Encerrando conexão.");

    in.close();

    out.close();

    socket.close();

    System.out.println("Encerrando servidor.");

    server.close();

}
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Socket e WebSocket](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/264647/socket-e-websocket)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem várias maneiras de fazer isso e libs prontas. Vou colocar aqui um exemplo js nativo.

```
function WebSocketTest()
         {
            if ("WebSocket" in window)
            {
               alert("WebSocket is supported by your Browser!");

               // Let us open a web socket
               var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:3000");

               ws.onopen = function()
               {
                  // Web Socket is connected, send data using send()
                  ws.send("Message to send");
                  alert("Message is sent...");
               };

               ws.onmessage = function (evt) 
               { 
                  var received_msg = evt.data;
                  alert("Message is received...");
               };

               ws.onclose = function()
               { 
                  // websocket is closed.
                  alert("Connection is closed..."); 
               };

               window.onbeforeunload = function(event) {
                  socket.close();
               };
            }

            else
            {
               // The browser doesn't support WebSocket
               alert("WebSocket NOT supported by your Browser!");
            }
         }
```

Nesta função ele verifica se seu browser suporta WebSocket. Depois ele abre a conexão na url que vc deve configurar.

`ws.onopen` é o evento que acontece logo que vc loga no socket.

`ws.onmessage` é o evento de quando você recebe uma mensagem

`ws.onclose` é o evento de quando a conexão é fechada

Comment: Seria interessante você fazer uma explicação !! Afinal o **AP** deixou claro que não entende muito sobre **JavaScript**.

Comment: Mas eu recebo um erro utilizando ela em meu navegador junto ao servidor ligado: " Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed "

Comment: Esse problema é pq seu código java está fechando a conexão.
`System.out.println("Encerrando conexão.");

    in.close();

    out.close();

    socket.close();

    System.out.println("Encerrando servidor.");

    server.close();`

Comment: Independente, ele gera um erro e fecha a aplicação, com ou sem os scripts de encerramento da conexão...

Comment: " Mensagem recebida do cliente [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]: 
 at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
 at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
 at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)... "

Comment: o q vc colou aqui foi uma mensagem de sucesso de mensagem recebida

Comment: Consegui resolver meu problema, mas obrigado pela cooperação!

Comment: seria interessante vc colocar aqui o que estava acontecendo, caso o problema seja no javascript, corrigir na minha resposta